# How to recursively find the children of parent in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Unable to write out the SQL Query based on complex logic defined below.

**Database: MySQL**

**Input :**

```
id  userId   parentid    
----------------------
1    1       0          
2    2       1            
3    3       1             
4    4       1           
5    5       2           
6    6       3        
7    7       0      
8    8       0
```

**Output Expected if userId = 1 :**

```
id  userId   parentid    
----------------------
1    1       0          
2    2       1            
3    3       1             
4    4       1           
5    5       2           
6    6       3
```

**Logic Used:**

if userId = 1 then check for parentId whose value is 1, the records are (we have to include the record of userID =1 as well)

```
id  userId   parentid    
----------------------
1    1       0          
2    2       1            
3    3       1             
4    4       1
```

Now in above record set check user id again in this example apart form userId = 1, there are three userId's i.e. 2, 3, 4. Now we have to see whose parent id is 2, 3 and 4. Now records are.

```
id  userId   parentid    
----------------------
1    1       0          
2    2       1            
3    3       1             
4    4       1           
5    5       2           
6    6       3
```

if we userId column again new userid visible are 5 and 6, but there is no parent id for 5 and 6. So this the final result set.

Comment: If you have an unlimited depth of parents, then you can only do this with a `select` query in MySQL using recursive CTEs.  That requires MySQL 8+.

Comment: Can we have any SQLQuery for the scenario mentioned above for limited no. of columns as of now atleast.

Comment: Easier done in a scripting language like PHP.